# Google API Autocomplete in SvelteKit

Tags: html, google-api, binding, sveltekit

I am building an application where I need to get the value return from the API and bind it to my variable. I have been stuck on this for days, and I couldn't go any further.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  let address = "";
async function addExample() {
        const response = await fetch(
            "https://api",
            {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "api-key":
                        "api-key",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    address: address,           
                }),
            }
        );
    }
</script>


<svelte:head>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-key&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async
        defer
    >
    </script>

    <script>
        let autocomplete;
        function initAutocomplete() {
            const input = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
            const options = {
                componentRestrictions: { country: "au" },
                strictBounds: false,
            };
            const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                input,
                options
            );
        }

        autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", onPlaceChanged);

        function onPlaceChanged() {
            address = autocomplete.getPlace();
        }
    </script>

</svelte:head>

<input
                    id="autocomplete"
                    placeholder="address"
                    type="text"
                    bind:value={address}
                /><br />
```

I tried to add my tag `svelte:head` inside the `script` tag but it didn't work, among others tries and due my lack of experience, I want if I'm doing this on the right way instead of waste more time on this. PS: I don't need to create a map or anything like that now. I just want to bind the value of autocomplete to my variable, so I will be able to fetch data into a database.

I have tried everything I could find googling but none of them worked. I am new with all this, and I don't know what else to think/try.

Answer (score 7):

I also had trouble figuring out how to access the variable from `svelte:head`. What worked for me was to use the Google Maps [JS API loader](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader) instead of placing the script inside `svelte:head`. This is for those who want to use the pre-built [autocomplete widget](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete) for Google Places Autocomplete.

To install, run:

```
npm i @googlemaps/js-api-loader
```

Then in your `+page.svelte`, you can use `onMount` to load it.

```
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

let autocomplete;
let address;

const options = {
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'au' },
    strictBounds: false
    };


onMount(() => {
  const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: 'GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY',
    version: 'weekly',
    libraries: ['places']
    });

  loader.loadCallback((e) => {
    if (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } else {
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
      options
    );

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
    }
});

  function onPlaceChanged() {
    address = autocomplete.getPlace();

    console.log(address.formatted_address);
    }
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" />
<pre>{JSON.stringify(address)}</pre>
```